# Approach to Create Floating Box UI in QT

Tags: python, qt

[image]

The "supports" bubble acts similar to a tool tip, when button is clicked it appears next to a button.

How is this bubble created? it allows widgets to be placed inside itself.
Is this a widget by itself or some sort of float layout? 
I am new to QT and couldn't figure out how to approach this, which widget to use to achieve this?

Comment: It could be a `QWidget` where the `clicked()` signal of the button is connected to a custom slot which calls `show()/hide()` of the `QWidget`...

Comment: How to show that arrow in the widget? Is there pre-defined class for such outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: A simple `QWidget`, shown on demand, and programatically placed next to the button you target.

Other options:

- `QMenu` and related classes can be used to create your own menu, but this would be quite painful to customize, and possibly not flexible enough for your case
- `QDialog` is the perfect match when you want an modal or independent window that you can drag around, waiting for user's input. But your's is static and not modal
- `QWidget` is the base class for all widgets in Qt, and it is completely multipurpose, and can be used as a container for other widgets. `QLayout` then provide structure to you content (alignement, sizing, ...)

**How to**

- (Optional) Create your widget's content in Qt Designer
- Instantiate your dialog when you create your UI
- Connect to the button "clicked" signal

  ```
  connect(mybutton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::showXButtonTooltip);
  ```
- Place your tooltip and show it

  ```
  void MainWindow::showXButtonTooltip()
  {
      // Get your button position relative to the common
      // parent with QWidget::pos() and mapToParent.
      // Or just use a fixed value...
      QPoint position;
      m_tooltipWidget.move(position.x, position.y);
      m_tooltipWidget.show();
  }
  ```

Be careful not to put your toolbox inside a layout, or you won't be able to "move" it, as this is the responsability of the Layout.